# Play local videos in backgoung - REACT

Tags: reactjs, video, render

I made an array of 3 local videos and I want them to change on home page as a background let's say every 5 seconds. I made an array, setup State, when I console.log state I see that console is calling a new video every 5 seconds, but on my screen only 1st video just keep looping. In a return on video source if I hard code video [0], [1] or [2] it will play that next video.

This is my code:

```
let videoArray = [Miami, Miami2, Miami3];

function Home() {
const [videos, setVideos] = useState(videoArray);
const [currentVideo, setCurrentVideo] = useState(0);

//CHANGE VIDEOS FROM ARRAY EVERY 5 SECONDS
useEffect( () => {

const interval = setInterval(() => {   
  setCurrentVideo(currentVideo => (currentVideo+1)%videos.length)  
 }, 5000);
 return () => clearInterval(interval);
 }, [videos]);

return (
    
    <div id='home' className='home-div'> 
    <video autoPlay loop muted className="video">
        <source src={videos[currentVideo]} type='video/mp4' />
       </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. It might help someone in the future. I guess it's not the best soltuionm, but it does what I wanted.

```
This function changes video onClick.

function playVideo(source) {
let video = document.getElementById('player');
video.src= source;
video.load();
video.play();
} 


This function changes video every 12 secods.
useEffect( () => {
const interval = setInterval(() => {   
    setCurrentVideo(currentVideo => (currentVideo+1)%videos.length)
    let video = document.getElementById('player');
    video.src= videos[currentVideo];
    video.load();
    video.play();    
    // console.log(currentVideo)
}, 12000);

return () => clearInterval(interval); 
}, [currentVideo]);




<video id="player" autoPlay loop muted className="video">
        <source id="source1" src={videos[currentVideo]} type='video/mp4' />
       </video> 
       {/* <p style={{background:'red'}}>{videos[currentVideo]}</p> */}
       <div className='buttons'>
           <button src={Miami} id="video1" onClick={()=>playVideo(Miami)}></button>
           <button src={Miami2} id="video2" onClick={()=>playVideo(Miami2)}></button>
           <button src={Miami3} id="video3" onClick={()=>playVideo(Miami3)}></button>
       </div>
```